# Temporary access of admin

Tags: remote-access

I have a consultant to do some email work, integrating with Salesforce, asking for access to Salesforce. Is there a way to give a temporary access with admin. We can give him admin access and then change password. How we can do this ? Give your suggestions.

Thanks
Vml

Answer (score 2):

If I was in this situation this is what I would do:

1. Plan do the entire integration activity in a sandbox that has all business objects and some test data.
2. For the permissions, I would first analyze as to what level of access is required, to which objects etc. (details of your "some email work"). Then, I would create or assign an existing profile or permission set depending on the results of my analysis. This allows me to reduce the System Administrator privileges further instead of just using the out of the box System Administrator profile. 
   For ex., if for integration work, only API level access is required, the profile or permission set (assuming salesforce license and not any other type) would have "API Only User" administrative permission. If necessary, I would also put in place login hours, ip range restrictions etc.
3. I would then create a user account with my email address as the email address of the user account and a suitable username for logging in. Then share the details with the consultant.
4. Finally when the work is done, I would deactive this account.